# Unable to migrate users

Tags: users, migrations

I have been using the migrate module to [migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) users from Drupal 7.59 to Drupal 7.59. I encounter the following error.

```
Migration for <em class="placeholder">NonDomainUserMigration</em> failed with source plugin exception: <em class="placeholder">SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054     [error]
Unknown column &#039;pgid&#039; in &#039;on clause&#039;</em>, in <em class="placeholder">/app/includes/database/database.inc</em>:<em class="placeholder">2227</em>
```

What could be the issue? I can't find any pgid column in the drupal database.

the following is my User migration code

```
<?php
abstract class NonDomainBaseMigration extends Migration {

  // A Migration constructor takes an array of arguments as its first parameter.
  // The arguments must be passed through to the parent constructor.
  public function __construct($arguments) {
    parent::__construct($arguments);

    // With migrate_ui enabled, migration pages will indicate people involved in
    // the particular migration, with their role and contact info. We default the
    // list in the shared class; it can be overridden for specific migrations.
    $this->team = array(
      new MigrateTeamMember('Moses Liao', 'moseslgz@sph.com.sg',
        t('Tech Lead')),
    );

    Database::addConnectionInfo('legacy', 'default', array(
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'database' => 'zaobao_drupal',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => 'password',
      'host' => 'mysqldb',
      'prefix' => '',
    ));
  }
}

class NonDomainUserMigration extends NonDomainBaseMigration {
  public function __construct($arguments) {

    parent::__construct($arguments);
    $this->description = t('Legacy Zaobao Drupal 7 system Users');

    $query = Database::getConnection('default', 'legacy')
    ->select('users', 'u')
    ->fields('u');

    $this->source = new MigrateSourceSQL($query);
    $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationUser();

    $source_key = array(
      'pgid' => array('type' => 'int',
                      'unsigned' => TRUE,
                      'not null' => TRUE,
                      'description' => t('Source ID'),
                     )
    );
    $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName, $source_key,
      MigrateDestinationNode::getKeySchema(), 'legacy', array('track_last_imported' => TRUE));

    $this->addSimpleMappings(
      array(
        'uid',
        'name',
        'pass',
        'mail',
        'theme',
        'signature',
        'signature_format',
        'created',
        'access',
        'login',
        'status',
        'timezone',
        'language',
        'picture',
        'init',
        'data',
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are using a source id key that does not exist. It should be uid.

Answer (score 0):

its seems to me that `pgid` is wrong. Should be `uid` for users